# Upload app to AppStore that only allows login

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to upload an app to the AppStore that only allows specific users to login? I have a website that hold certain amount of users, I want to develop an app only for those users. The app won't allow anyone new to register to the application, only login for those existing users.

Will Apple allow this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When they have logged in will the users be able to do anything else or is it just log in and that's it at that point you are just on a screen that says logged in?

Comment: They will be able to do some functions related to the website, I have some 20 screens with data and functionality inside. But my problem is the login area. I only allow login, without registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.

Apple does not allow apps that have very limited functionality.
If you provide some nice functionality for those users, then it should be no problem.

Comment: You could use your 30 characters to be more descriptive than just "yes".